# Python returns this error when I quit my window without use the button 'arret'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop, tkinter-canvas, coords

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random as rd
import math as mt
import time

fin = 0

def touche (event):
    global xa, xb, ya, yb
    key = event.char
    print(key)

def arret ():
    global fin
    fin = 1
    
def boucle ():
    global a,b,xa,xb,ya,yb,x0,y0,x1,y1,r
    x = xa+10
    y = ya
    r = (xb-xa)/2
    for i in range (0, len(a)):
        x0 = x-a[i]*r
        y0 = y-b[i]*r
        x1 = x+a[i]*r
        y1 = y+b[i]*r
        can.coords(helice,x0, y0, x1, y1)
        can.update()
        time.sleep(0.02)
        
fen = Tk()

fin = 0

key = 'v'

can = Canvas(fen, bg = 'deep sky blue', width = 200, height = 200)
can.pack()

quit = Button(fen, text = 'quit', command = fen.destroy)
quit.pack(side = BOTTOM)

xa = rd.randint(5, 195)
ya = rd.randint(5, 195)
xb = xa+20
yb = ya

list_color = ['black', 'lavender blush', 'aquamarine', 'blue violet', 'tomato', 'dark cyan', 'green yellow', 
              'medium spring green']
number = rd.randint(0,7)
for i in list_color:
    if list_color.index(i)==number:
        color = i
    
helice = can.create_line(xa, ya, xb, yb, width = 4, fill = color)

arret = Button(fen, text = 'arret', command = arret)
arret.pack(side = BOTTOM)

a = [-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1]
b = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

while fin != 1:
    boucle()

    
fen.bind ('<Key>', touche)
 
fen.mainloop()
```

The return :

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [71], in <cell line: 64>()
     62 b = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
     64 while fin != 1:
---> 65     boucle()
     68 fen.bind ('<Key>', touche)
     70 fen.mainloop()

Input In [71], in boucle()
     26 x1 = x+a[i]*r
     27 y1 = y+b[i]*r
---> 28 can.coords(helice,x0, y0, x1, y1)
     29 can.update()
     30 time.sleep(0.02)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:2766, in Canvas.coords(self, *args)
   2762 """Return a list of coordinates for the item given in ARGS."""
   2763 # XXX Should use _flatten on args
   2764 return [self.tk.getdouble(x) for x in
   2765                    self.tk.splitlist(
-> 2766            self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]

TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

I have tried to create a function to solve the problem but it doesn't work.
And if I click on my button named 'arret' Python don't show me this error but for the next exercice that I have to do. I must add an keyboard event which is not able to run before the 'click'.

I think the problem come to my while loop but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random as rd
import math as mt
import time

fin = 0

def touche (event):
    global xa, xb, ya, yb
    key = event.char
    print(key)

def arret ():
    global fin
    fin = 1
    
def boucle ():
    global a,b,xa,xb,ya,yb,x0,y0,x1,y1,r,fin
    try:
        while(fin !=1):
            x = xa+10
            y = ya
            r = (xb-xa)/2
            for i in range (0, len(a)):
                x0 = x-a[i]*r
                y0 = y-b[i]*r
                x1 = x+a[i]*r
                y1 = y+b[i]*r
                can.coords(helice,x0, y0, x1, y1)
                can.update()
                time.sleep(0.02)
    except:
        pass
        
fen = Tk()

fin = 0

key = 'v'

can = Canvas(fen, bg = 'deep sky blue', width = 200, height = 200)
can.pack()

quit = Button(fen, text = 'quit', command = fen.destroy)
quit.pack(side = BOTTOM)

xa = rd.randint(5, 195)
ya = rd.randint(5, 195)
xb = xa+20
yb = ya

list_color = ['black', 'lavender blush', 'aquamarine', 'blue violet', 'tomato', 'dark cyan', 'green yellow', 
              'medium spring green']
number = rd.randint(0,7)
for i in list_color:
    if list_color.index(i)==number:
        color = i
    
helice = can.create_line(xa, ya, xb, yb, width = 4, fill = color)

arret = Button(fen, text = 'arret', command = arret)
arret.pack(side = BOTTOM)

a = [-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1]
b = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

fen.after(0, boucle)
  
fen.bind ('<Key>', touche)
 
fen.mainloop()
```

or you can use this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random as rd
import math as mt
import time

fin = 0

def touche (event):
    global xa, xb, ya, yb
    key = event.char
    print(key)

def arret ():
    global fin
    fin = 1
    
def boucle ():
    global a,b,xa,xb,ya,yb,x0,y0,x1,y1,r,fin
    
    while(fin !=1):
        x = xa+10
        y = ya
        r = (xb-xa)/2
        for i in range (0, len(a)):
            x0 = x-a[i]*r
            y0 = y-b[i]*r
            x1 = x+a[i]*r
            y1 = y+b[i]*r
            if(fin!=1):
                can.coords(helice,x0, y0, x1, y1)
                can.update()
                time.sleep(0.02)
   
def die():
    global fin
    fin=1
    fen.quit()
    fen.destroy()        
fen = Tk()

fin = 0

key = 'v'

can = Canvas(fen, bg = 'deep sky blue', width = 200, height = 200)
can.pack()

quit = Button(fen, text = 'quit', command = die)
quit.pack(side = BOTTOM)

fen.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", die)

xa = rd.randint(5, 195)
ya = rd.randint(5, 195)
xb = xa+20
yb = ya

list_color = ['black', 'lavender blush', 'aquamarine', 'blue violet', 'tomato', 'dark cyan', 'green yellow', 
              'medium spring green']
number = rd.randint(0,7)
for i in list_color:
    if list_color.index(i)==number:
        color = i
    
helice = can.create_line(xa, ya, xb, yb, width = 4, fill = color)

arret = Button(fen, text = 'arret', command = arret)
arret.pack(side = BOTTOM)

a = [-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1]
b = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

fen.after(0, boucle)
  
fen.bind ('<Key>', touche)
 
fen.mainloop()
```

have fun :)